# Finding the kth smallest element using randomized quicksort giving logical errors

Tags: algorithm, sorting, c++11

So I tried using quicksort for finding the kth smallest element in a vector. But while implementing it my logic is somewhere wrong. And so Im getting wrong answer.I used rand() to generate pivot indexes randomly then shift the pivot index to the right most side of the vector. Check this out:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;
void swap(int& x,int &y)
{
    int temp=x;
    x=y;
    y=temp;
}


template<typename comp>
int randompart(vector<comp>& a,int l,int r)
{
    int asize=r-l+1;
    int pi=rand() % asize;
    swap(a[l+pi],a[r]);

    int x=a[r];

    //create 3 vectors small,same and larger 
    vector<comp> s;
    vector<comp> sa;
    vector<comp> la;

    //if current element is smaller than x then push it to smaller vector 
    //else push it to larger or same vector
    for(auto& i:a)
    {
        if(i<x)
            s.push_back(move(i));
        else if(i>x)
            la.push_back(move(i));
        else
            sa.push_back(move(i));     
    }    
    int f=s.size()+sa.size()-1;
    return f;

    move(s.begin(),s.end(),a.begin()); 
    move(sa.begin(),sa.end(),a.begin()+s.size());
    move(la.begin(),la.end(),a.end()-la.size()); 

}


template<typename comp>
int kthsmallest(vector<comp>& a,int l,int r,int k)
{
    if(k>0 && k<=r-l+1)
    {
        int pos=randompart(a,l,r);

        if(pos==k)
            return a[pos];
        else if(pos>k)
            return kthsmallest(a,l,pos-1,k);
        else
            return kthsmallest(a,pos+1,r,k-pos+l-1);    
    }
    return INT_MAX;
}


int main()
{
    vector<int> n({7,10,6,3,12,9});
    int c=kthsmallest(n,0,n.size()-1,3);
    cout << c;

    return 0;

}
```

As you can see it gives me wrong answers. SO can someone please let me know where i went wrong?.

Comment: Are you supposed to do the `move` calls in the `randompart` function? Perhaps you should not `return` from the function before that?

Comment: Consider using `std::swap` instead of writing your own version. Besides, if you really need to use `rand`, you should also call `srand` once.

Comment: Find a small ailing example and debug your code processing it.

Comment: Is `int asize=r-1+1;` what you really mean (`int asize = r;`) or a typo (`int asize=r-l+1;`)? That's a good example of the risks of using `l` as a variable name.

Comment: @Bob__ Yes you were right I wrote 1 in place of l but still im getting errors. and this time a run failed error.

Comment: `std::partial_sort` will re-order a collection such that the kth smallest elements appear first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely it is a problem with updating the value of k. The trick is that you already decrease the relative position of k by increasing the left range border. Just think what happens when l becomes non-zero. Hence there is no need to decrease k further.